# Making an header.php [Bootstrap3]

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do some basic HTML and PHP. 
What I would like to do is, take this template:

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/

And cut the menubar out of the index.html, and make that into a seperate header.php, so I can use it on my other pages as well.

I tried just cutting the code out of it, then pasting it in the header.php and including this. However it does not show up.

Could anyone explain to me how I should do this, I read about it on W3Schools that it could be something with the CSS.

I tried copying this over, to it with no success.
(The code: http://pastebin.com/6XKNaw98)

If someone could explain me how I can make the menubar of this template into a seperate header.php file, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Show us you code to check what you have tried, please.

Comment: @Bcesars, I could only post two links at a time, sorry.
http://pastebin.com/rN7MmkHk header.php
http://pastebin.com/6XKNaw98 index.php

Comment: are you really sure it is a HTML page which the nav menu taken separately with include - php ? if it is right, you can not do include function inside HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want the navbar from this template, get the source code and copy paste only the html declaration which provide this navbar into a header.php.

Next, You have to echo the html like

```
echo "<nav class='some-bootstrap-class'>
         <ul>
             <li>Some item</li>
             ....
         </ul>
      </nav>";
```

Finally, include it into your html with the include function like on your pastebin.

Please note that echoing (don't know how to say it) html like this in PHP is pretty ugly (for me and other web developpers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I tried what you said, I made this:
- http://pastebin.com/VFNDPw8F
- 

It still does not show up, could you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Thais hmm, try to change "include" to "require_once" because if your file isn't found, It'll display you an error

Be also sure when you inspect your dom with your inspector that you have the outputed nav

Comment: Changed it.
Now I get a blank page, I guess I turned error reporting off.
http://pastebin.com/VFNDPw8F header.php
http://pastebin.com/NS2D1zFW index.php

Comment: If possible, you could add me on skype.
I could share you my files, and you could help me.
Only if you want of course, hehe.

Comment: @Thais in your index.php, replace require_once by :

die(var_dump(file_exists("location of your file)));
if you have "true" on your screen, your file exists and is found
if you have "false", that's why your code doesn't works :)

Comment: Hmm, I suspect I f@cked something up.
When including and using the die, I get a blank page.
When removing that part, It work (except the navbar)
http://gyazo.com/322b1df964c5a2a804387a30a87c4464 and my header.php http://gyazo.com/b36ddb7ef57021fed07031f7d5de6b4f

Comment: @Thais

is your wamp|mamp|lamp running with a green logo ?
if you open your php bracket at the top of index.php and write "echo 'something';", have you the displayed message on your screen ?

does PHP work in your page ?

Comment: You missed up your double quotes on your index.php in the file_exists

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for being this retarded and wasting your time.
What I did wrong was, <?php include "/includes/header.php"; ?>
Placing the "/" infront of the includes made it a non-valid directory.
Sorry, and thanks for your time!

Comment: @Thais no problem, I knew it were a problem of include, that's why I told you to use file_exists :p

Comment: Thanks, any way to give you some sort of reward?
Reputation?

Comment: @Thais no lol, you already accepted by answer as the best answer ^^